# parameterized constructor for inherited class templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17

I have multiple inherited class, bur getting error `C2<int (__cdecl *)(int)>': no appropriate default constructor available`, but I defined parameterized constructor for `C1,C2`.

A related question is I have seen commented line marked `???` in some code. What does it mean - it is initializing default constructor for  `C2` from `C3`?

```
#include <iostream>
int y(int) 
{ int a=1; return a } 

template<typename F>
class C1
{
public:
    F f1;
    C1(F g) : f1(g) {}  
};

template<typename F>
class C2 : public C1<F>
{
public:
    F f2;
    C2(F g) : f2(g) {}  
};

template<typename F>
class C3 : public C2<F>
{
public:
    F f3;
    C3(F g) : f3(g) {}
    //C3 (F g) : C2<F>(g) {}        ???
};


int main()
{
    C1 o1(y);
    C2 o2(y);
    C3 o3(y);
}
```

Comment: C1 does not have a default constructor, only a constructor that takes a parameter. C2 inherits from C1, but invokes C2's default constructor, which does not exist. Same problem with C3 that inherits from C2, for the same reason. Compiler's error message is pretty clear, and says exactly that. The ??? is an example of constructing a superclass by invoking its constructor. But that by itself will not fix this, the same thing is needed for C2's invocation of C1's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct a class that is child to another class, the parent's default constructor (unless another one is explicitly called like in line marked `???`) is invoked. But seeing as you provided a constructor for each class, the compiler did not generate an implicit default constructor. So when you create an instance of `C2`, and the compiler tries to call the missing default constructor of `C1`, it can't find it.

If you do provide a default constructor, this works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int y(int) {
    int a=1;
    return a;
} 

template<typename F>
class C1 {
public:
    F f1{};

    C1() = default;

    C1(F g)
        : f1(g)
    { }  
};

template<typename F>
class C2 : public C1<F>
{
public:
    F f2{};

    C2() = default;

    C2(F g) 
        : f2(g)
    { }  
};

template<typename F>
class C3 : public C2<F>
{
public:
    F f3{};

    C3() = default;

    C3(F g) 
        : f3(g) 
    { }
    //C3 (F g) : C2<F>(g) {}        ???
};


int main()
{
    C1 o1(y);
    C2 o2(y);
    C3 o3(y);
}
```

The line marked `???` calls a specific parent constructor instead of relying on the implicit call to the parent class' default constructor.

So you can either provide default constructors like above, or you can adopt the `???` line syntax to call a specific constructor -- this depends on your class design and intentions.

Comment: I am bit confused here. At the time of instantiating child class object, say `o2` in this case, does compiler calls only default constructor of parent class or *any* constructor of parent class?

Comment: When you use the `C2(F g) : f2(g) { }` syntax, where you don't explicitly call `C1`'s constructor, the compiler will try to implicitly (behind the scenes) call `C1`'s _default_ constructor. But if your `C2` constructor uses the `C2(F g) : C1<F>(g), f2(g) { }` syntax, where you do explicitly call _some_ `C1` constructor, the compiler will not try to do anything implicitly and you get exactly what you write.

Answer (score 1):

As Sam says, `C2`s constructor is trying to call the default constructor for `C1`, which doesn't exist.  Likewise, `C3` is trying to call `C2`s default constructor.

There are two fixes:

- define default constructors for `C1` and `C2`, or:
- modify `C2`s constructor to call a constructor that does exist, like so:

  `C2(F g) : C1 <F> (g), f2(g) {}`
- and similarly `C3`s constructor, like so:

  `C3(F g) : C2 <F> (g), f3(g) {}`

Which, in itself, answers your second question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

`C2<F>(g)` initializes the base class by calling its constructor. If you don't call a constructor yourself then the compiler will attempt to call default constructor for the base class (`C2<F>::C2()`) instead. None of your classes have default constructors which is the source of the error. But really what you should be doing is calling the base class constructors yourself.

```
C2(F g) : C1<F>(g), f2(g) {}
C3(F g) : C2<F>(g), f3(g) {}
```